# Errors with GPT and installing Ubuntu alongside Windows7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, gpt

I have a brand new Dell laptop with a 512e hard drive using GPT. Ubuntu 12.04 in Live CD mode does not recognize the presence of Windows 7 or any partition for that matter: it shows a completely blank HD. Windows 7 Professional was installed this morning along with a partition set aside for Ubuntu.

I tried boot repair, here is the log:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5895278

And there was no new result.

I have a feeling it is the Advanced format of my HD that is causing the problem. Does anyone see a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with your Advanced Format hard disk. The problem is identified by the following line in your Boot Repair log:

```
GUID Partition Table detected, but does not seem to be used.
```

This indicates that the disk *used to be* a GPT disk, and was incompletely converted to MBR format, presumably by the Windows installer. The easiest immediate solution to this problem is to finish the job. My [FixParts program](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) is the easiest way to do this. Run it on the disk and it will complain about the leftover GPT data. Tell it to go ahead with deleting the data and then quit from the program.

Note that your Windows is installed in BIOS mode, so you should be sure to install Ubuntu in the same way. Your installation program might launch in either BIOS mode or in EFI mode. I'm not sure how it will respond if you accidentally boot it in EFI mode. To avoid any possibility of problems, I recommend dropping to a text-mode shell and looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode, which means you should reboot and select a different boot option to get the computer to boot in BIOS mode instead.